# Delete dangling pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, dangling-pointer

After this code _var2 is `Dangling pointer`.

```
int* _var = new int(102);
auto _var2 = _var;
delete _var;
```

Must i delete _var2 (`delete _var2`)? Is it inevitable?

Comment: `_var2` points to the address of a defunct object. If anyone can de-reference it, you should make it point to a valid object or `nullptr`.

Comment: both `_var2` and `_var` are *indeterminate* as soon as you delete *either*. Only delete *one*. (or better still, [use smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory))

Comment: An [**example**](http://ideone.com/UXb2lO) of one way of maintaining pointer concurrency with smart pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because it's already been deleted.

The `delete` keyword doesn't really delete a *pointer*, it deletes *the value that it points to*.  In this case, you allocate the integer 102 on the heap on line 1, and then you delete that integer on line 3.  Both your pointers (`_var` and `_var2`) still hold the address where the integer *was*, but it's not there anymore.  `delete _var2` would be incorrect because there's nothing allocated at that address.

Comment: I suspect the OP might be thinking that C++'s `delete` keyword works similar to JavaScript's `delete` operator.

Comment: I wonder how easier life would have been for millions of C++ beginners if the keyword had been named something like `delete_at`... :)

Comment: @Wyzard I'm new to C++, but I don't think this is exactly correct. The value that was in the memory location _may_ still be there, or it may not. All delete does is make that memory address available for other pointers created with the new operator.

Comment: @pyetti, as an implementation detail, you're correct (at least for typical computers), but as far as the C++ language is concerned, after the `delete`, there's no longer an `int` at the location that the pointer points to.  It's irrelevant what values might remain in the underlying bytes in RAM, because you're not allowed to dereference the pointer to see them.  It's like when you delete a file on your computer: the contents may remain in the sectors on the hard drive, but there's no longer a *file* there, and you can't delete the file a second time because it's already gone.

Answer (score 1):

i recommend to you that use from "std::tr1::shared_ptr" to manage resources.
in "effective c++" by Scott Meyers in chapter 3 has useful info about it.

Answer (score 0):

upd.
In common case, you don't need to do it, because the it points will be already deleted. If you need to work with pointers, it is better to set the pointer to NULL after you deleting it:

```
int* _var = new int(102);
auto _var2 = _var;
...
if(!!_var)
{
delete _var;
_var = NULL;
}
```

Comment: What @Wyzard said, you're calling `delete` on a pointer that points to some memory that can't be `deleted`. Also, there is no need for the `!!` comparisons.

Comment: to avoid this kind of problem is better use `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: Setting a pointer to NULL after deleting sounds like a guideline from the early 90s. Today, I think the consensus is that if you need this kind of convention, then you are actually just shadowing the real problems of your code and design.

Comment: @ChristianHackl, it's still entirely reasonable if the pointer will remain in scope and other code needs to be able to tell whether it currently points to something or not.  It's not necessarily a design problem to have an object that sometimes exists (allocated on the heap) and sometimes doesn't (null pointer).  (Of course, it's probably a design problem to be using a raw pointer instead of a smart one for this purpose.)

Comment: @ChristianHackl, not necessarily. Someone consider, that using of raw pointers - it's a "dirty" way to programming in modern world. But i think, it is better to understand how it works "under the hood".

Comment: @Wyzard: For control flow which is actually designed like this from the ground up, it's sometimes OK, and I've used this pattern myself. But the guideline is often used as kind of an error-checking or error-prevention mechanism, along the lines of "if some other piece of code will later accidentally delete the pointer again, the program may crash, so better set it to NULL right away, so the program will not crash". This IMO means to silently accept erroneous program states and to shadow bugs.